Where has struct file_operations::readdir() gone?
I have an old kernel module, which assigns my my_readdir function to  file_operations::readdir.  I would like to update my module to be compatible with 6.X kernels.  I've already fixed issues with the arguments of .create and .mkdir.
On https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/locking.html#file-operations it talks about file_operations::readdir moving.  It is not in file_operations on that page, so I assume that the comment below is stale.

->readdir() and ->ioctl() on directories must be changed. Ideally we would move ->readdir() to inode_operations and use a separate method
for directory ->ioctl() or kill the latter completely. One of the
problems is that for anything that resembles union-mount we won’t have
a struct file for all components. And there are other reasons why the
current interface is a mess...

readdir() didn't go to inode_operations: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8.7/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2035
How do I tell a modern 6.X kernel about my module's my_readdir function, which I used to do by assigning it to file_operations::readdir ?

As far as I understand, you are looking for file_operations::iterate_shared function. Exactly that function is used in implementation of iterate_dir, which is replacement for vfs_readdir. When define functions for that field, FS drivers are still name those functions like "readdir": .iterate_shared = btrfs_real_readdir, so probably the semantic of "new" function is the same as of the old readdir.

Change log: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/porting.html?highlight=iterate_dir  vfs_readdir is replaced by iterate_dir and readdir is replaced by iterate_shared.
